# EJB Timer for deleting database entries

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am currently working on a j2ee web application. The application features a way for users to reset their passwords if they forget them.

I have a database table with 3 columns: username, key, and timestamp. 
When the user requests a password change, I add an entry in that table with their username and a random key (making sure that their are no duplicate keys in the table, also that a user can only appear once in the table). I also add the current time. I then send them an e-mail with a link to the application that contains their key, something like:

```
mysite.com/app/reset?key=abcxyz123
```

The servlet that handles this request looks at the key in the url to find the matching entry in the reset table to determine which user the key belongs to. If the key doesn't match an entry, I show an error page, if it does, I show the password reset screen. Once the user changes their password, I manually delete the entry from that reset table.

I am trying to implement the equivalent of a time to live for the password reset links, so that I don't have entries loitering in the table unnecessarily, and I thought of 2 options, the first of which I have implemented:

1) Create an EJB Timer that fires every minute that will delete entries in the reset table where the timestamp is older than 30 minutes. This is a manual process in that I am using hibernate as my jpa implementation, so I retrieve all the entries from the table, examine their timestamps, and delete the old ones.

2) Create a database job that deletes rows over a certain age?

My question is, does anyone see any drawbacks to the first approach, and second, is the 2nd option even possible with mysql? I figure that if I can use the 2nd approach, I can get rid of the timer, and let the database handle the time to live aspect of the password reset links, and that may be more efficient.

I haven't been doing j2ee development for that long, but based on the knowledge that I have, these seemed like 2 logical approaches. I welcome any input.

Answer (score 0):

3) Create script that will connect to db, execute delete, disconnect. Then you can schedule this script via operating system e.g. crontab.

Regarding option 1 - Drawback of that solution is that it uses application server resources for stuff that can be done on database only and is not dependent/uses any application logic.

Benefit is that whole app is self contained and you don't need any additional installation/setup task on database as with 2 and 3.